# replace a field value from another in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am novice to elastic search.I have a tran_timestamp field in (yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS) format in my csv file.Using logstash want to add another field in the output as (YYYY-mm-dd) format.Kindly help in achieving the same.

CSV :

```
actor_id,actor_type,tran_id,tran_date,tran_type,tran_sub_type,acid,cr_dr_indicator,tran_amt,orig_input_amt,tran_particulars,tran_particulars_2,tran_remarks,r_cre_id,channel_id,use_case,sub_use_case,circle
12345,ABC,123,2016-01-31 05:55:13,ITM,103A,10554566,CR,0.500000,0.500000,Total  Amount of SCW ,TM_1=0.5,,SYSTEM,DEFAULT,,,KL
```

Config is attached
[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zrsD.png)

Comment: Will it be fine for you if you use `scipted_fields` to derive it from existing field

Comment: @siddharthajain are you around?

Comment: @val i have been trying to accept and up voted them but not visible for now probably because i am new on stack over flow.

Comment: As ok I see, sorry to bother you then.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a simple `mutate` filter, where you [`split`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-split) the date in the `tran_timestamp` field and then only take the first element which you [add to a new field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field) (that I called `tran_day`)

```
filter {
  csv {
    ...your CSV config...
  }
  mutate {
    split => {"tran_timestamp" => " "}
    add_field => {"tran_day" => "%{[tran_timestamp][0]}"}
  }
}
```

Comment: while i am throwing it to slandered  output it's returning me "tran_timestamp" => "2015-12-23 12:45:47","tran_day" => "%{[tran_timestamp][0]}", while i am expecting output as "tran_day" => "2015-12-23" . Kindly help.

Comment: Sure thing. Please update your question with your Logstash config and the sample line you're using.

Comment: have put the description kindly check

Comment: You need to move the `csv` filter above the `mutate` one like in my answer. Moreover, your date field is named `tran_date` and not `tran_timestamp`, so make sure to adapt it accordingly. Please try and let me know.